# scroll bar not showing for the entire screen

Tags: android, user-interface, scrollbar, scrollview

I have used the scroll view  in my application. if there are are too many items , the vertical scroll bar appears. But if there are only few items ,then the vertical scroll bar doesnt appear for the full screen. Is it possible to show a scroll bar for the full screen?

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/tile_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/banner_btn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/banner"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:ellipsize="end" />

                    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_right_columns"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:paddingRight="10dip"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/left_column"
                            android:layout_marginRight="9dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" />

                        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/right_column"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="vertical" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

Comment: why do you need scrollbar if there is not items to scroll.

Comment: if there are enough items to exactly fill the entire screen,and if there is no scroll bar of the full screen, if we try to scroll it seems like scroll view is not responding. so if we are able to show the fill screen scroll bar we can indicate the users that no more items available.

Comment: @kannappan:which language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use `XML` attribute of `ScrollView` like this

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
```

See [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack) for more information.

Comment: i tried this but still the scroll bar for the entire screen is not appearing